# Sync ajax without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to perform a **sync** ajax call without using jquery?

Clarification: because there is a need to load a remote JSON resource *before* any of remote js scripts are executed, and then continue page loading.

Comment: Does [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855) help you?

Comment: @RenéRoth question is about *sync*, not *async* call.

Comment: This question has been answered, I believe, here: [STACKOVERFLOW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)  and here is how to make in synchronous [MOZILLA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Especially [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()) - note that `open` has an `async` parameter.

Comment: A better answer might be to examine why you need to do this and if there isn't a better way to handle it. Synchronous calls will degrade the user experience. Nobody likes their browser to freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

This question has been answered, I believe, here on how to do a non-ajax call: [STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)  and here is how to make in synchronous (where I got this answer from) [MOZILLA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)